# TSQL - Create Table Design

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a -

```
Table X  
------------------------------------
TaskId (bigint-identity-primary key)  
Data1 (varchar), Data2(varchar)
```

Now, I am creating a new Table -

```
Table Y 
------------------------------------
Id (identity, Primary Key)
TaskId(FK to Table X)
Data3(varchar)
```

Now, since Table X and Table Y will have a one-one relationship based on the TaskId column, so **what and how** should do I define the Primary Key, Index, etc on **Table Y** ?

Also, is it worth having an identity column at all as Primary Key if it will never be used in where clause 
 ? I have just added it by convention.

Comment: Lets call `TableX` table `Task` and `TableY` table `Y`. Is every Y a Task? Or is every Task a Y? Or both?

Comment: If every Y is a Task and every Task is related to **one** Y only (as the 1:1 implies) and not to many (as the FK definition implies), then use `Y.TaskId` as both the `Primary Key` and a `Foreign Key`to Tasks.

Comment: I should have said: *"and every Task is related to **zero or one** Y"*

Answer (score 3):

Since this is `1:1` relationship, and every `Y` is a `Task` you can use this approach:

```
Table Y 
----------
TaskId (bigint),
Data3 (varchar),
PRIMARY KEY TaskId, 
FOREIGN KEY TaskId REFERENCES Task(TaskId)
```

I guess this is useful if only a few Tasks are Y-Tasks and not all of them. And you prefer not to have `NULL`s in your tables.

Comment: Actually, all `Y` data will refer `Tasks` data. It is strict 1:1. I am not a DB expert. The Table X previously did not have that column. So, as you all believe, I went ahead and added my new column in Table X, but I saw that performance degraded by 10% while doing a select query on Table X after adding this column. And, this new column is just a read-only column. hence, I am trying to make a new table such that Table X remains as is.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a one-one relationship, why create a whole new table `Y`? Just add the new `Data3` column to Table `X`.

Comment: That was the design, but due to performance issues, it is being separated.

Comment: Performance could improve if you apply [Vertical Partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178148.aspx) but if that's the case, the design structure of Y should be kept the same as that of X and the question is moot.

Comment: @JNK - I am not a DB expert. The Table X previously did not have that column. So, as you all believe, I went ahead and added my new column in Table X, but I saw that performance degraded by 10% while doing a select query on Table X after adding this column. And, this new column is just a read-only column. hence, I am trying to make a new table such that Table X remains as is.

Comment: If it's a strict `1:1` (and not `0..1:1` as I thought), splitting the table like this is Vertical Partinioning as @Lieven mentioned. See his link for pros and cons of the approach. It's possible you could gain performance in some situations. It's also possible you might have your original approach, with one table, without problems. Perhaps the addition of the column caused fragmentation of the table in disk? No idea about that. Someone with expertise on SQL-Server may advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have a 1:Many relationship...

Keep your PK and Clustered index key on the `ID` field.

Create a non-clustered index on `TaskID, Data3` or, if you never filter on `Data3` and only `SELECT` it, just `INCLUDE (Data3)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you must separate it and you are sure that it will always remain 1-1, then use taskID as the PK. If it could be 1-many inteh future, add an identity and put a unique index on taskid. Then if you go 1-many all you have to do is drop the unique index.

Comment: But won't the inserts be slow for 5 million + kind of record size if I make TaskId as the PK ?

Comment: I can't see why they would be any slower than if you had an identity field. You still need the FK to the first table. SO it has to check that anyway. You still need it to be unique so it is either check it as the PK or check it using the unique index. But you don't have to generate the ids.